# Why is dlib so slow finding an object?

Tags: image-recognition, dlib, dlib-python

I'm testing some stuff with Dlib and I selected rectangles around instances of an object I want to recognize, using the compiled tool included in tools/imglab/build/imglab. With this xml file describing a few different views of the object I want to detect I run the train object predictor with a few changes:

```
training_xml_path = os.path.join(faces_folder, "cooldataset.xml")
testing_xml_path = os.path.join(faces_folder, "cooldataset.xml")
```

and running in the images directory, makes a detector.svm.

Now I run a modified object detector for an image, it detects many of the objects it should and puts a rectangle around them, yet it takes almost 2 seconds to find them in a 1920x1080 screenshot! This is on a i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz × 4 so I wonder if there is some compression or other step that I'm missing to make it go faster or work on less powerful device. This is compiled on Ubuntu from dlib-18.16 if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Dlib's object detector for similar situation and I have 20 fps on 1920x1080 relotion with the similar processor

First of all - get latest version from github
After that ensure that you have AVX support enabled (**-mavx**) and you are compiling optimized code (**-O3 or -Ofast**)

As I see - you are using Python interface for Dlib. To compile it, you should call :

***python setup.py install --yes USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS***

(follow readme.txt instruction in dlib's folder)

Comment: The default instructions don't set that? Is AVX also applicable if I ran it on a Raspberry Pi (ARM processor)?

Comment: cat /proc/cpuinfo will show you if your CPU supports AVX or not

Comment: Raspberry has ARM processor inside, some ARM's have SIMD support but you should check it and I think that instrincts will be differents. default support of SIMD in GCC normally enables SSE/SSE2 in x64 mode and disable in x86. AVX/AVX2 should be enabled manually

Comment: @Evgeniy dlib's face detector takes more time to detect face's bounding box instead where landmark point's detection is fast. How it can become fast.

Comment: @Evgeniy With what version did this work? Assuming you're using cmake, and the `compile_dlib_python_module.bat` I think you have to enable `option(USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS  "Compile your program with AVX instructions"  ON)` and similar in the dlib/cmake file, and after compiling Dlib, set `SET(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)` without the # commenting it, in dlib/add_python_module.

Comment: @Evgeniy What was taking 1.8s is now taking 1.4s pretty consistently, still not that great of a speedup. I am on Dlib 18.16.

Comment: v 19, c++ api, ubuntu

Comment: After issuing this command it shows `The --yes options to dlib's setup.py don't do anything since all these options 
are on by default.  So --yes has been removed.  Do not give it to setup.py.
` that means it is enabled by default. So what are the other things going wrong?