# Dlib's simple_object_detector() is running slowly

Tags: python, performance, object-detection, dlib, histogram-of-oriented-gradients

I have trained a `SVM` model for `simple_object_detector()`. But while inference on a video it is becoming too slow.

I went through a similar question: [Why is dlib so slow finding an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37157702/6907424) where an answer is saying to use `USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS` flag enabled while `dlib` installation. But it is not the case for me. As I found the flag is enabled by default. I also have come through this FAQ: [Why is dlib slow](http://dlib.net/faq.html#Whyisdlibslow) where the solution is to choose the `Release` mode in `Visual Studio` but I am not using `Visual Studio` and just running the code from terminal.

But interesting thing is that if I run the builtin face detector `dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()` it runs completely fine with no lag. But the program only becomes slow while running `simple_object_detector()` trained on custom data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright! I got the solution. Actually I missed to provide a flag while running the detector. Probably it is related to some optimization.

First initialize the detector object:

```
detector = dlib.simple_object_detector("/path/to/your/trained/SVM/detector")
```

Now change the following line from this:

```
detections = detector(gray_image)
```

To this:

```
detections = detector(gray_image, 0)
```

**Reference:**
https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/557#issuecomment-297679025